# How to get Xcode to refresh folder references on device?

Tags: xcode, reference, build, directory, run-script

I created a folder reference by doing the following:

1. Created a folder on disk. Added whatever files are meant to be in it.
2. In Xcode
       ---> Add files to project
       ---> Clicked on folder
       ---> Unchecked copy files if necessary
       --->Clicked create folder references for any added folders

The problem:
Whenever I make changes to files in the folder (add/delete) etc. The changes are picked up in Xcode. (You can see the changes in project navigator). These changes are not there when I run on the simulator. Deleting the application on the simulator does not help. Only when I click "Reset content and Settings" in the simulator, does it pick up the changes.

I already have added the following script to my build phases:

```
touch -cm "${BACKGROUND_TEXTURES}"
```

It is run after compiling, but before copying bundle resources. My bundle resources contain this folder.

I'm not sure whether the script matters, since Xcode picks up the changes with to without it. It's the simulator that doesn't get updated, unless I manually set "Reset content and settings".

What is the correct way to solve my problem?

EDIT: I have tried Clean, then Build, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Example:
I create "Images" folder at project folder, and I "create folder references for any added folders".
Next I add `touch -cm ${SRCROOT}/../../Images` to Run Script,And I drag "Run Script" before to "Compile Sources"
clean and build,it's ok.

Comment: I add a folder named "Images" under the Resources folder.
Next I add touch -cm ${SRCROOT}/../../Images to Run Script,And I drag "Run Script" before to "Compile Sources"
but it's not working. I don't know why